# Integral $\int\limits_{b-a}^{b+a} \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - (x-b)^2}}{x} \text{d} x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I’m trying to solve this integral:
$$\int\limits_{b-a}^{b+a} \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - (x-b)^2}}{x} \text{d} x$$
As you can see it isn’t an easy integral to do in cartesian coordinates. However, given the fact that the numerator describes the upper half of the circumference $(x-b)^2 + y^2 = a^2$ this integral could be simpler in polar coordinates.

Yet I’m confused as to how can I use this idea. In polar coordinates $x = r \cos (\theta)$ so $\text{d}x = \cos(\theta) \text{d} r - r\sin(\theta) \text{d} \theta$. Do I have to substitute $x$ and $\text{d}x$ in order to solve the integral in polar coordinates? Am I even right in thinking that polar coordinates should be used to solve this integral?

Comment: Substitute $x=a\cos \theta +b.$

Comment: Note that this substitution is possible because $a \cos \theta +b$ has a range of $[b-a,b+a]$.

Comment: I’ll try this hint, thank you.

Comment: Assuming $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b>a$, *Mathematica* gives:  $\pi  \left(b-\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\right)$.

Comment: I plugged it in Mathematica as well (with the hypothesis you mentioned). However I was trying to solve it and it proved to be lengthy. Maybe in other coordinate system it was easier to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $b>a>0$. Let $x=b+a\sin t$ and $u=\arctan(\frac t2)$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int_{b-a}^{b+a} \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - (x-b)^2}}{x} \text{d} x\\
&=&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{a^2\cos^2 t}{b+a\sin t}dt\\
&=&2a^2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{(u^2-1)^2}{(u^2+1)^2(bu^2+2au+b)}du\\
&=&2a^2\int_{-1}^{1}\left[-\frac{2u}{(u^2+1)^2}+\frac{b}{u^2+1}+\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2(bu^2+2au+b)}\right]du\\
&=&2a^2\left[\frac{b\pi}{2a^2}+\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2b}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{u^2+\frac{2a}{b}u+1}du\right]\\
&=&2\left[\frac{b\pi}{2}+\frac{a^2-b^2}{b}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{(u+\frac{a}{b})^2+\frac{b^2-a^2}{b^2}}du\right]\\
&=&b\pi+\frac{2(a^2-b^2)}{b}\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{b(u+\frac{a}{b})}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right)\bigg|_{-1}^1\\
&=&b\pi-2\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{b+a}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{-b+a}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right)\right)\\
&=&b\pi-2\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=&\pi(b-\sqrt{b^2-a^2}).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I arrived at the second integral (the one with the variable of integration $u$), then I got stuck. I didn't think of using partial fractions. Thank you for your answer

Comment: You are welcome.